# If $G_3$ is finitely generated abelian group then there is a short exact sequence with $G_2$ and $G_1$ free groups?

Tags: abelian-groups, exact-sequence

Let $G_i$ be abelian Groups. A exact sequence of the form $ 0 \to G_1 \to G_2 \to G_3 \to 0$ is called a short exact sequence. Is the following statement true?

If $G_3$ is finitely generated then there is a short exact sequence with $G_2$ and $G_1$ free groups?

I'm unable in producing a counter example.please help.

Comment: An exact sequence with only two nonzero terms is just an isomorphism. It should have all three $G_i$ in it.

Comment: Indeed; your question should probably be, "Is there a (split?) short exact sequence $0 \to G_1 \to G_2 \to G_3 \to 0$?" Perhaps to help us answer, you should say what your definition of "finitely generated" is. (You should also probably include the map $f$ in your initial description, since otherwise it makes no sense.)

Comment: @user26857 Sorry,fixed now.Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that a sequence $$0\to G_1 \to G_2\to G_3\to 0\tag{*}$$is short exact. Set
$$G_3=\Bbb Z_{a_1}\times \Bbb Z_{a_2}\times \cdots \Bbb Z_{a_n}\times \Bbb Z^m$$ If $G_1=\Bbb Z^n, G_2=\Bbb Z^{n+m}$ and $f:G_1\to G_2$ is given by first multiplying each component with the corresponding $a_i$, then adding $m$ zeroes to the end, the sequence $(*)$ is exact.

Comment: Sorry..How do you define map from $G_2$ to $G_3$?

Comment: @Learner I send $(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$ to $(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$, and let linearity of group homeomorphisms take care of the rest. Alternatively, I send any $(b_1, \ldots, b_{n+m})$ to $(\bar b_1, \bar b_2,\ldots, \bar b_n, b_{n+1}, b_{n+2},\ldots,b_{n+m})$ (that's the same thing, only said a bit differently).

Comment: @Learner I mean, of course, group _homomorphisms_, not homeomorphisms.

Comment: Ofcourse thats true!